# Joomla JEvent - Different calender category needs different access

Tags: joomla, calendar, categories

I'm using the extension **JEvent** to manage a calender in Joomla.

There are 2 categories:

- Party events
- Training events

I need ***2 registered users***, who only ***have access to only one category***.

- party-organizer -> Party events
- and trainer -> Training events

*How do I do this?* Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know JEvent(s) but normally on extensions, which are running on actual versions of Joomla (1.6+), if they support categories, permissions can be set per category. Means you can assign the two users to different user groups and set the permissions on the category for each user group. Do the same with the access level.

I suggest to read the Joomla ACL tutorial http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Access_Control_List_Tutorial

Comment: Correct: JEvent supports categories. This allows to use the Joomla access levels. Thanks.

Comment: Nice to hear that it works, now I explained you how to use you a product of a competitor of me :-)